# Grease Pencil, drawing straight lines v 2.78

Tags: add-on, grease-pencil, movie-clip-editor

I am trying to find the focal length and camera position using the BLAM addon for the image below:

[image]

I try to draw the required lines in red (entering <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>) but blender only draws horizontal lines and vertical lines. What did I forget to do ?

Comment: Suppose the owner of the addon is not willing or interested to update the addon. What is 'best practice' if you would like to have the addon updated ? I think it is open source.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the add-on or maybe some of the recent changes on the grease pencil's funcionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw straight lines select Draw>Line on the grease pencil section.

[image]

Otherwise press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and place the cursor on the starting point of the straight line, then release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while still holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key, and position the end point of the line and release the <kbd>D</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: in mac os it is opt+D